# AWS XRay template is properly creating the EC2 instance but not able to connect using instance connect or do ssh to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-cloudformation, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I have the following cloudformation template it is creating the ec2 instance properly but not able to connect to the ec2 instance with either instance connect or ssh from putty. I have seen other answers suggesting to attach internet gateway to the subnet , I have done that it still does not work:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
        "60dcb39c-cc02-4b3a-bc24-159bb4641b6d": {
            "size": {
                "width": 60,
                "height": 60
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 150,
                "y": 90
            },
            "z": 1,
            "embeds": [],
            "iscontainedinside": [
                "f249024f-80d9-4123-8e23-c94b2a3369bc"
            ]
        },
        "27de666e-5af9-44ee-bfa5-67e48f8cce27": {
            "size": {
                "width": 60,
                "height": 60
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 240,
                "y": 90
            },
            "z": 1,
            "embeds": [],
            "iscontainedinside": [
                "0c56b978-8a45-40dc-9691-635296a3fa7e"
            ]
        },
        "f249024f-80d9-4123-8e23-c94b2a3369bc": {
            "size": {
                "width": 90,
                "height": 90
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 360,
                "y": 90
            },
            "z": 1,
            "embeds": []
        },
        "0c56b978-8a45-40dc-9691-635296a3fa7e": {
            "size": {
                "width": 90,
                "height": 90
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 930,
                "y": 150
            },
            "z": 1,
            "embeds": []
        },
        "7ca9ec38-462f-4daa-be8e-3360b3396a7b": {
            "size": {
                "width": 60,
                "height": 60
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 270,
                "y": 210
            },
            "z": 1,
            "embeds": []
        },
        "45db66a4-341b-4870-90e9-408effaccabd": {
            "size": {
                "width": 60,
                "height": 60
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 420,
                "y": 270
            },
            "z": 1,
            "embeds": []
        }
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "vpc1": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
        "Properties": {
            "CidrBlock": "70.70.0.0/16",
            "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
            "EnableDnsHostnames": "true"
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "0c56b978-8a45-40dc-9691-635296a3fa7e"
            }
        }
    },
    "subnet1": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "vpc1"
            },
            "CidrBlock": "70.70.0.0/24",
            "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
            "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a"
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "f249024f-80d9-4123-8e23-c94b2a3369bc"
            }
        }
    },
    "secGrp1": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupName": "secGrpNm",
            "GroupDescription": "secGrpDesc",
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "vpc1"
            },
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 8080,
                    "ToPort": 8080,
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ],
            "SecurityGroupEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "Description": "Allow all traffic"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "27de666e-5af9-44ee-bfa5-67e48f8cce27"
            }
        }
    },
    "ec2": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-0376ec8eacdf70aae",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a",
            "KeyName": "kipee",
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Ref": "instanceProfile1"
            },
            "NetworkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
                    "DeviceIndex": "0",
                    "SubnetId": {
                        "Ref": "subnet1"
                    },
                    "GroupSet": [
                        {
                            "Ref": "secGrp1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "60dcb39c-cc02-4b3a-bc24-159bb4641b6d"
            }
        }
    },
    "instanceProfile1": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
        "Properties": {
            "Path": "/",
            "Roles": [
                {
                    "Ref": "role1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "7ca9ec38-462f-4daa-be8e-3360b3396a7b"
            }
        }
    },
    "ig1": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
        "Properties": {}
    },
    "gateway1": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": { "Ref": "vpc1" },
            "InternetGatewayId": { "Ref": "ig1" }
        }
    },
    "role1": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Path": "/",
            "Policies": [
                {
                    "PolicyName": "XrayWriteOnlyAccess",
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": [
                                    "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                                    "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
                                    "xray:GetSamplingRules",
                                    "xray:GetSamplingTargets",
                                    "xray:GetSamplingStatisticSummaries"
                                ],
                                "Resource": "*"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                "id": "45db66a4-341b-4870-90e9-408effaccabd"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Below is the event log while for the stack:

[image]

I am getting timeout error when connecting with the keypair in putty:

[image]

And this is the instance connect error:

[image]

**Update 1:**

I added network Act in cloud formation and the error changed but I am still not able to connect :

```
"netAcl1": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl",
  "Properties": {
    "VpcId": { "Ref": "vpc1" },
    "Tags": [
      { "Key": "Name", "Value": "netAcl1" }
    ]
  }
},
"MyNetworkAclInboundRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
  "Properties": {
    "NetworkAclId": { "Ref": "netAcl1" },
    "RuleNumber": 100,
    "Protocol": "6",
    "RuleAction": "allow",
    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
    "Egress": false,
    "PortRange": {
      "From": 22,
      "To": 22
    }
  }
},
"MyNetworkAclOutboundRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
  "Properties": {
    "NetworkAclId": { "Ref": "netAcl1" },
    "RuleNumber": 100,
    "Protocol": "6",
    "RuleAction": "allow",
    "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
    "Egress": true,
    "PortRange": {
      "From": 22,
      "To": 22
    }
  }
}
```

The new error is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems apart from networkAcl I was also missing few other resources like route,routetable,subnetroutetableassociation. The following example worked for me to be able to do ssh , although it still did not fix the instance-connect , but for now I am okay with atleast ssh working :

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyVpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "true"
      }
    },
    "MySubnet": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "MyVpc"
        },
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a"
      }
    },
    "MyInstance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId": "ami-0376ec8eacdf70aae",
        "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
        "KeyName": "kp1",
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash\n",
                "echo 'Hello, World!' > /tmp/hello\n"
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        "NetworkInterfaces": [
          {
            "DeviceIndex": "0",
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
            "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
            "SubnetId": {
              "Ref": "MySubnet"
            },
            "GroupSet": [
              {
                "Ref": "MySecurityGroup"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "MySecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "MyVpc"
        },
        "GroupDescription": "Allow SSH and HTTP traffic",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": 22,
            "ToPort": 22,
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          },
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": 8080,
            "ToPort": 8080,
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }
        ],
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "MyInternetGateway": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
      "Properties": {}
    },
    "GatewayAttachment": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "MyVpc"
        },
        "InternetGatewayId": {
          "Ref": "MyInternetGateway"
        }
      }
    },
    "PublicRouteTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "MyVpc"
        }
      }
    },
    "PublicRoute": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
      "DependsOn": "GatewayAttachment",
      "Properties": {
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "PublicRouteTable"
        },
        "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "GatewayId": {
          "Ref": "MyInternetGateway"
        }
      }
    },
    "PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "MySubnet"
        },
        "RouteTableId": {
          "Ref": "PublicRouteTable"
        }
      }
    },
    "MyNetworkAcl": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "MyVpc"
        }
      }
    },
    "MyNetworkAclEntryIngress1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
      "Properties": {
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "MyNetworkAcl"
        },
        "RuleNumber": 100,
        "Protocol": "6",
        "RuleAction": "allow",
        "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "Egress": false,
        "PortRange": {
          "From": 22,
          "To": 22
        }
      }
    },
    "MyNetworkAclEntryEgress1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
      "Properties": {
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "MyNetworkAcl"
        },
        "RuleNumber": 100,
        "Protocol": "6",
        "RuleAction": "allow",
        "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "Egress": true,
        "PortRange": {
          "From": 22,
          "To": 22
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```